# how can I achieve a text field with a drop down prefix in flutter

Tags: flutter

how can I achieve this in flutter? I tried using the DropdownButton as a child of the `prefixIcon` in the `InputDecoration` of a `TextFormField` but it doesn't come out well. I would love to know how people will solve this when faced with such challenge.

[image: this]

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `ListTile` and put the `DropDownButton` and the `TextField` in a `Row` and set the `Row` as the `title` of the `ListTile`. The `ClipRRect` is used for making the rounded corners.

```
ListTile(
  title: ClipRRect(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
    child: Container(
      color: Colors.black12,
      child: Row(
        children: [
          _buildDropDownButton('USD'),
          Expanded(
            child: TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: InputBorder.none,
              ),
              controller: textController,
              style:
              TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.black),
              keyboardType:
              TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

```
Widget _buildDropDownButton(String currencyCategory) {
  return Container(
    color: Colors.deepPurple,
    child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 5),
      child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
        child: DropdownButton(
          iconEnabledColor: Colors.white,
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          dropdownColor: Colors.deepPurple,
          value: currencyCategory,
          items: ['USD', 'EUR']
          .map((String value) => DropdownMenuItem(
            value: value,
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(value),
              ],
            ),
          ))
          .toList(),
          onChanged: (value) {},
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Result:

[image: res]